# Nodejs Passport display username in html page

Tags: html, node.js, express, passport.js

In *nodejs/.ejs* file, I can display the user name as follows:

```
<% if (!user) { %>
    <h2>Welcome! Please <a href="/login" >Login</a>.</h2>
<% } else { %>
    <h2>Hello, <%= user.displayName %>.</h2>
<% } %>
```

How to do the same in html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you a *static* html page.  The short answer is that you can't-- that's what makes it a static page.

The longer answer is that if you have that html page include some JavaScript that then performs an AJAX call to the server to fetch the username, you can.  Look into jQuery `$.get` function if you're choosing this approach.